# for while loop with counter python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop, counter

I have a data frame where the index is vendors and there is a column for different months for the order quantity ordered by them for that given month.

| Vendor | January order qty | February order qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2478 | 3567 |

The variables are vendor which is a list containing the name of all the vendors, col which is a list of the names of the columns.

The output desired is the list of vendors for each month that have order quantity below 1.
The loop should go through each vendor and append to a list the name of the vendor if it meets the condition.
The loop should go through the range of vendor items and after it has gone through the vendor list, 1 will be added to the counter so the next column name is targeted.
This is repeated until the end of the column list is reached.
I am relatively new to python/pandas so my code could need some work. It was running for 5 mins so I assumed something was not correct with it.

The below is an example of code targeting the January, February and March column.For some reason only jan list works correctly.

```
jan= []
feb=[]
march=[]
c= 0 

for i in range(0, len(vendor)):
    if c==0:
        if df.loc[vendor[i], col[c]]< 1:
            jan.append(vendor[i])
            if vendor[i]== len(vendor):
                c+=1
    elif c==1:
        if df.loc[vendor[i], col[c]]<1:
            feb.append(vendor[i])
            if vendor[i]== len(vendor):
                c+=1
    elif c==2:
        if df.loc[vendor[i], col[c]]<1:
            march.append(vendor[i])
            if vendor[i]== len(vendor):
                c+=1
```

Comment: If the `if` condition isn't true, you never increment `c` or break out of the loop, so you have an infinite loop. I don't think you want a `while` loop at all, just  the `c > len(...)` condition to break out of the `for` loop early.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do? Example inputs with corresponding outputs.

Comment: I want a list of vendors who have 0 and below values from each column (each column is for each month). 
So the loop should check each vendor and see if the month has a below 0 value and if it does it appends it to the list. The comment below has the data frame. 
c is a counter to go to the next item in month list.

I will like to make a list for each month. Once the counter reaches the length of the month list, it should break.

Answer (score 0):

hope you like it

## For one month (jan)

```
jan = list(df.loc[df[col[0]] < 1].index)
```

## For all months

```
All_Mounth_List = []

for i in range(12) :
    All_Mounth_List.append(list(df.loc[df[col[i]] < 1].index))
```

Comment: Dataframe is here : https://ibb.co/myW2tyG
vendors is left most column/index
c is the column #.
I want to create lists for each month of the vendors that had order quantities below 1.

Comment: @SamGrewal no, you must provide the example in the question itself. Don't link to off-site resources, give a small example, only big enough to demonstrate what you are trying to accomplish, not your whole data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: edited the question, hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient/elegant approach but it works.
Suggestions for improvement are appreciated.
I ended up using itertools to create a list of tuples for each vendor, month combination:

```
import itertools

for i in range(0, len(col_list_ord_qty)):
    if i ==0:
        ord_qty_jan = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[0])))
    elif i ==1:
         ord_qty_feb = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[1])))
    elif i ==2:
         ord_qty_march = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[2])))
    elif i ==3:
         ord_qty_april = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[3])))
    elif i ==4:
         ord_qty_may = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[4])))
    elif i ==5:
         ord_qty_june = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[5])))
    elif i ==6:
         ord_qty_july = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[6])))
    elif i ==7:
         ord_qty_aug = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[7])))
    elif i ==8:
         ord_qty_sept = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[8])))
    elif i ==9:
         ord_qty_oct = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[9])))
    elif i ==10:
         ord_qty_nov = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[10])))
    elif i ==11:
         ord_qty_dec = list(zip(vendors, itertools.repeat(col_list_ord_qty[11])))
```

Then I ran a loop to check below 1 order quantity values(one loop :

```
low_ord_qty_jan =[]
for i in range(0, len(ord_qty_jan)):
     if df_ord_qty.loc[ord_qty_jan[i]] <1:
          low_ord_qty_jan.append(ord_qty_jan[i])
          jan_low_vendors = [idx for idx, val in low_ord_qty_jan]
```